# multiple ajax request $.when on jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Using $.when on jquery for deffered ajax had some drawbacks. It's great when ajax calls were processed successfully. But if one fails, you can't get the other data on the other request.

Ex.

```
    var ajax1Success = function() { 
       return $.ajax(...);
    };

    var ajax2Success = function() { 
       return $.ajax(...);
    };

    var ajax3BoundtoFail = function() { 
       return $.ajax(...);
    };


    $.when(ajax1Succes(), ajax2Success(), ajax3BoundtoFail()).done(function(a1, a2, a3) {
       // all good

    }).fail(function() {
       // not good... ajax3 is bound to fail
    });
```

Any good solution how to get other data from ajax request that succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

`$.when()` has a "fail fast" design.  That means that the first promise that fails causes `$.when()` to reject and you only get the reject info.  From the jQuery doc:

> The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the
>   Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the
>   Deferreds is rejected

You can, however, use a different type of function to monitor your group of promises.  This type of functionality is often called "settle" where you wait for all promises to settle and you get the results from all of them no matter whether they resolved or rejected.

Here's such an implementation for jQuery promies that I have used in the past that you can use like this:

```
$.settle([ajax1Succes(), ajax2Success(), ajax3BoundtoFail()]).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of PromiseInspection Objects
    // for each of them, you can see if the corresponding promise
    // succeeded with a value or failed with an error
    results.forEach(function(pi, index) {
        if (pi.isFulfilled()) {
            console.log("Promise #" + (index + 1) + " succeeded with result " + pi.value());
        } else {
            console.log("Promise #" + (index + 1) + " failed with reason " + pi.reason());
        }
    });
});
```

Or, a bit simpler version to use if you don't need the exact error:

```
$.settleVal(null, [ajax1Succes(), ajax2Success(), ajax3BoundtoFail()]).then(function(results) {
    // results contains the results from all the successful promises
    // any promises that has an error will show null as the result
});
```

Note, these use an interface more like the standard `Promise.all()` where they take an array of promises and resolve to an array of results as this tends to be generally easier to use in the real world.

And, here's the implementation:

```
(function() {    

    function isPromise(p) {
        return p && (typeof p === "object" || typeof p === "function") && typeof p.then === "function";
    }

    function wrapInPromise(p) {
        if (!isPromise(p)) {
            p = $.Deferred().resolve(p);
        }
        return p;
    }

    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, isRejected: function() {
                return !fulfilled;
            }, isPending: function() {
                // PromiseInspection objects created here are never pending
                return false;
            }, value: function() {
                if (!fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .value() on a promise that is not fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }, reason: function() {
                if (fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .reason() on a promise that is fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }
        };
    }

    // pass either multiple promises as separate arguments or an array of promises
    $.settle = function(p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        }

        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            // make sure p is a promise (it could be just a value)
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            // Now we know for sure that p is a promise
            // Make sure that the returned promise here is always resolved with a PromiseInspection object, never rejected
            return p.then(function(val) {
                return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
            }, function(reason) {
                // convert rejected promise into resolved promise by returning a resolved promised
                // One could just return the promiseInspection object directly if jQuery was
                // Promise spec compliant, but jQuery 1.x and 2.x are not so we have to take this extra step
                return wrapInPromise(new PromiseInspection(false, reason));
            });
        })).then(function() {
              // return an array of results which is just more convenient to work with
              // than the separate arguments that $.when() would normally return
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        });
    }

    // simpler version that just converts any failed promises
    // to a resolved value of what is passed in, so the caller can just skip
    // any of those values in the returned values array
    // Typically, the caller would pass in null or 0 or an empty object
    $.settleVal = function(errorVal, p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        }
        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            return p.then(null, function(err) {
                return wrapInPromise(errorVal);
            });
        }));
    }
})();
```